# CORS not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cors

I've set up Cross-Origin Resource Sharing on a server (Jetty using the CrossOriginFilter) and it works perfectly on IE8 and Firefox.  On Chrome, it just ... doesn't.

```
  $.ajax({ url : crossOriginURL,
    type : "GET",
    error : function(req, message) {
        alert(message);
    },
    dataType :  "json" } );
```

The error function is invoked, with the helpful message "error".  It seems to be making the request, but without any of the headers you'd expect.  If the URL is from the same origin, it works fine.

Comment: Malvolio and CuSS are same person?

Comment: No! Of course not! LOL. I had the same problem has him today morning. It was urgent to me to resolve that, so to don't repeat the question, i've bounty on his question, but since I've resolved it now, i had answer it. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

what finally worked for me is `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');`

**EDIT:** The server needs to add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` to avoid this problem.

I am coming back to my own question *a decade later*.  I don’t know if this is a good thing or a terrible thing.

Comment: To explain this a bit more fully, using "raw" data like this avoids the preflighting that is more common with CORS.  Since there's no pre-flight, there's no access control checks, which avoids the entire issue.  +1

Comment: @Richard That's only half right. It avoids the preflight, but even non-preflighted CORS requests can produce errors (for example, if there is no matching `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ...` response header. The reason this works is actually very simple: `text/plain` is one of very few content types that are allowed without an *explicit* `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` response header. `json` (or `application/json` requires the explicit header allow.

Comment: @CBHacking -- seven goddamn years later and someone comes up with the right answer.  I don't know if it's good or bad that seven years later, and I check the website within two hours.  Anyway, why don't you make an answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 27):

**I have solved my problem this way:**

Add this to your PHP Code:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");
```

Or add these headers to your response.

Problem: The browsers ask to the server for options before your main request, to check if the site has the option to allow comunication with different origin, and then if yes, they do your POST or GET request.

**EDIT:** Try this (without your hack) to see if you're receiving data...

```
$.ajax({ url : crossOriginURL,
    type : "GET",
    error : function(req, message) {
        alert(message);
    },
    success : function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    dataType :  "text"} );
```

Comment: Actually, what finally worked for me is xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

Comment: In that case, can you post your own answer and mark THAT as the correct one? (I don't have this particular problem, but I do like to keep the list of unanswered questions clean)

Comment: my answer works to all browsers. You don't need to request custom headers because who restricts or not the page is server and browser engine... if you were receiving a blank response, problaly it was bad dataType on ajax, that happens because you didn't choose the right dataType. Read about dataType in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ .   

in ajax options array place the {dataType:"text"}

Comment: The solution to set the content type to plain didn't work for me (I get an error indicating I can't set that on the request).

And I'm not writing my own server service, I'm using another one online (twitter).

Is there another solution using JavaScript only? 

I also tried setting the "origin" to something specific using the same technique as above (setting the request header), but got an error.

My code is working just fine in Safari but fails in Chrome, even though all indications are that Chrome supports CORS.

Comment: do you have access to server? check jsonp

Comment: I can't get CORS working in Chrome.  I have control of the server, I bounce back the requested Method, Headers and specific Origin that I receive on the request, and the browser still fails to send the XHR request.  If anyone has this working with Javascript, could you post up the OPTIONS message and the returned response as an example please?

Comment: @CuSS Perfect answer ! I had already included the above said headers at the server side. Still was not able to fetch the headers via AJAX calls. Then i read about the `'Problem: '` part you mentioned in the answer, and it helped me. I was adding `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` as the 2nd last header. When I changed the order(kept it as the first header), it worked for me. Also I have only set `type: 'GET'` in the options. Keeping `dataType: 'jsonp'` doesn't return the header for me, it only returns me the response/data. This may help others who are facing similar issues.Thanx again

Comment: @CuSS `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` are **mutually exclusive!** Conforming user agents (browsers) will **reject** (error) the response to any credentialed CORS request if the server responds with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`; the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header *won't even be checked* because it is **not allowed** with wildcard allowed origins. See [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Credentialed_requests_and_wildcards).

Comment: @CBHacking this is a response from 2010. 6 years ago only Chrome had CORS.

Comment: ... and I'm pretty sure `ACAO: *` and `ACAC: true` were incompatible back then, too, the Mozilla docs were just the first ones I came to. (FWIW, IE8 had partial CORS support back in 2009, but credentialed requests weren't supported anyhow.)

Comment: I have a similar problem, my application is built using Angular 7. I am making an ajax call to a BPMS server which works fine in IE but I have a CORS error in Chrome. However when I copy the ajax url to the Chrome browser I have all the data. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 15):

It looks like the original poster may have resolved their issue, but for anyone having the same issue as commentor Elisabeth, I believe the problem may be that Chrome refuses to set a an Origin header for a CORS request if you are running the request from a local file.  It won't even let you explicitly override the Origin header.  This causes the server to see "Origin: null", which results in a 403 in most cases.  Firefox apparently has no such constraint, as I've found after much hair-pulling.

If you absolutely need to use Chrome in this case, you can resolve your issue by running a webserver locally and always accessing your file via http: instead of via file:.

Comment: A less intrusive (albeit temporary) resolution can be obtained by running Chrome with cross-origin security *turned off*:  `path/to/chrome --disable-web-security`.  **Warning**: if you continue to use unsecured Chrome for your regular browsing, either nothing will happen or your bank account will be hacked, so good luck with that.

Comment: This really saved my day! As soon as I put the originating request behind a simple web server, everything was ok.

Answer (score 3):

Check to make sure that you didn't set your server to both allow credentials and set the allow origin header to *. Like below:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

If your server is returning these values for these headers, then it will not work. If you set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true`, then you can't use `*`as the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Below is an excerpt from the MDN webdocs for the header(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin):

```
For requests without credentials, the literal value "*" can be specified, as a wildcard; 
the value tells browsers to allow requesting code from any origin to access the resource. 
Attempting to use the wildcard with credentials will result in an error.
```

If the above is the case, simply set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `false`.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
```

### References

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Answer (score 2):

When i updated the chrome i was facing the problem,I've solved it Google Extension "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" new version. if it is an old version,you will not need to work on a new Google Chrome version

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/access-control-allow-cred/hmcjjmkppmkpobeokkhgkecjlaobjldi?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

We actually have two domains, one is for the dashboard `dashboard.app.com` and another one is the public website `app.com`. The request was coming from the public website and the PHP routing was redirecting to the dashboard domain, that is why we got the error. The solution was to keep all the request within the same domain, without redirects.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it's localhost:8001 (the front-end) which tries to call the APIs at localhost:7001 (on server.js as a Node server). Even I had the CORS plugin installed and turned on on Chrome, still the CORS policy rejected them as preflight cases.

It took me more than half day to finally resolve the issue.
Here are the "stupid" steps, believe it or not:

i. Turn OFF the CORS plugin, reload the app, at this time you should still get the errors which are correct.

ii. Turn it back ON, reload the app, if the APIs are successful, stop here, no need to proceed to iii.

iii. However if you still get the CORS rejection, then uninstall Chrome and install an up-to-date Chrome.

iv. On the new Chrome, the previously installed CORS plugin should still be there but with OFF status.

v. Reload the page, you should get the CORS rejection messages on console which are correct.

vi. Turn it back ON, reload the page, the errors should disappear.

No further ideas if the above steps still do not work in your case.

I also tried the following on server.js (Node) and still do not work, so no bother to try:

```
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors'); // Already done “npm i cors --save-dev”
app.options('*', cors());
```

Answer (score -9):

CORS will work in chrome. Just use chrome is safe-mode, i.e., use disable security settings.
Google it about it, or you can even start from command line also.

Comment: That isn't a good solution because (a) it's inherently *un*-safe, (b) it requires the user to stop Chrome and then restart it before my site will work, and (c) I needed the solution *three years ago!*