# Why are response headers null from CORS AJAX response?

Tags: jquery, playframework, playframework-1.x, response-headers

An AJAX request, using jsonp, to an external Play! 1.2.4 application on Heroku, which returns data successfully, returns null on`getResponseHeaders()`.

Here is my code:

```
var ajaxresult;
    ajaxresult = $.ajax({
    'complete': function (jqXHR, status) {            
        console.log('Complete!');
        console.log(status);
        console.log("on compelte: " + jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
    },
    'dataType': "jsonp",
    'error': function (jqXHR, status, error) {
        console.log('Error!');
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
        console.log("on error: " + jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
    },
    'success': function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log('Success!');
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);
        console.log("on success: " + ajaxresult.getAllResponseHeaders());
        console.log("on success(2): " + jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
    },
    'type': 'GET',
    'url': url + "findAllSpecials"
});
```

If I dump the contents of jqXHR, I get:

```
"readyState: 4","setRequestHeader: function(a,b){if(!s){var c=a.toLowerCase();a=m[c]=m[c]||a,l[a]=b}return this}","getAllResponseHeaders: function(){return s===2?n:null}","getResponseHeader: function(a){var c;if(s===2){if(!o){o={};while(c=bG.exec(n))o[c[1].toLowerCase()]=c[2]}c=o[a.toLowerCase()]}return c===b?null:c}","overrideMimeType: function(a){s||(d.mimeType=a);return this}","abort: function(a){a=a||\"abort\",p&&p.abort(a),w(0,a);return this}","done: function(){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}","fail: function(){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}","progress: function(){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}","state: function(){return e}","isResolved: function(){return!!i}","isRejected: function(){return!!i}","then: function(a,b,c){i.done(a).fail(b).progress(c);return this}","always: function(){i.done.apply(i,arguments).fail.apply(i,arguments);return this}","pipe: function(a,b,c){return f.Deferred(function(d){f.each({done:[a,\"resolve\"],fail:[b,\"reject\"],progress:[c,\"notify\"]},function(a,b){var c=b[0],e=b[1],g;f.isFunction(c)?i[a](function(){g=c.apply(this,arguments),g&&f.isFunction(g.promise)?g.promise().then(d.resolve,d.reject,d.notify):d[e+\"With\"](this===i?d:this,[g])}):i[a](d[e])})}).promise()}","promise: function(a){if(a==null)a=h;else for(var b in h)a[b]=h[b];return a}","success: function(){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}","error: function(){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}","complete: function(){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}","statusCode: function(a){if(a){var b;if(s<2)for(b in a)j[b]=[j[b],a[b]];else b=a[v.status],v.then(b,b)}return this}","status: 200","statusText: success"]
```

The response headers as seen in Opera and Firefox are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Play! Framework;1.2.4;prod
Set-Cookie: PLAY_FLASH=;Expires=Fri, 5-Oct-12 12:47:15 GMT;Path=/
Set-Cookie: PLAY_ERRORS=;Expires=Fri, 5-Oct-12 12:47:15 GMT;Path=/
Set-Cookie: PLAY_SESSION=...
Content-Length: 1290
Connection: keep-alive
```

Why is is that using `getAllReponseHeaders()` returns null when the browser can see the headers? Does cross domain requests prevent response headers from being sent to the AJAX response?

All help is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i'm afraid that most of the browser's (Mozilla,Safari,Chrome) does not yet support `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` so your `getAllReponseHeaders()` will not work..

its been raised as a bug in mozilla firefox forums. But recently they have a fix here is the link you can check it out [This](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41210)

Answer (score 3):

Your server should return the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`header with the whitelist of headers that can be read, as defined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers).

I was able to use this header with Firefox 18 and Chrome 24. I think browser support is not a problem here, at least according to [this site](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors).

Be sure to return this header within the response of your GET (or POST, PUT, DELETE), not just with the OPTIONS method from "preflighted" requests.

Comment: That depends on your server language. If you are using a Java server, you can write a servlet filter that adds the headers like this: `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "User-Agent, Content-Type, *");`. If you don't want to write your own filter, you can use [this implementation from ebay](https://github.com/eBay/cors-filter) and just configure it.

Comment: Thank you for posting andrecardoso. I actually got my issue fixed. You can take a look at my comment in this ticket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136140/cors-not-working-on-chrome/3600086#comment30368211_3600086

Comment: @andrecardoso: You mean `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`.  `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is only for the preflight request _(as I painfully discovered today after hours of debugging)_