# CORS not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, http-headers, cors

I am trying to implement CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) on my web application. This is the structure:

- Site example.com: contains a couple JS files (jquery.js, myscript.js)
- Site example2.com: load both scripts from example.com, then call for one function from myscript.js, which makes a POST request to example.com

example2.com code would be something like:

```
<script src="http://example.com/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">startFunction(1, 2)</script>
```

Both JS are loaded fine on site B. However, when the function is called and the POST (standard jQuery $.post) performed, I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/postrequest. Origin
>   http://example2.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I went to example.com server and updated the .htaccess like this:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

I checked if the headers are being sent and indeed they are being sent. Accessing example2.com using Firefox, JS files are loaded and the POST request is successful. However, if I try to do exactly the same with Chrome, it still fails. I have been dealing with this for some hours and still I am not able to see what is wrong with this. Is this a Chrome bug or something?

I have to point out that I checked similar questions and applied some of the solutions, but I did not have success.

**Update**: Tried the suggested solution adding this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    }
});
```

And indeed the Content-Type is set, but the same error keeps happening, so this did not solve anything.

Comment: See answer for similar question: [CORS not working on Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136140/cors-not-working-on-chrome)

Comment: I have checked that link already (you can notice because the Allow-Headers header is exactly the same as the linked question).

Comment: But what about `'Content-Type'` header in your request?

Comment: Browser is sending the following Content-Type when performing the POST: `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. It should be allowed as the "Content-Type" header is listed in the .htaccess file.

Comment: For the sake of completion, also try adding `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.  I have seen some examples recently where Chrome behaves differently than Firefox due to cookies.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not make it work either.

Answer (score 0):

How is your server setup?

Do you have some load balancing or any other kind of request handling between different systems? Are you using Apache, NGINX, etc. ? (I suppose Apache due to htaccess?

Because in that case there are some things you have to pay attention.

**Is the mod_header installed?**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
</IfModule>
```

In most cases content and method type is not needed.
Except if you're using Options requests.

Try to also use the Allow-Headers rule.

Please check if the rule Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" is only once in your request. (Maybe sent from the app or setup in the apache config, e.g. vhost?)

**And can you please post the request header incl. response header?**

(Pls. use Chrome delveoper tools, network tab, and than please the RAW(!) header)