# javascript json working in firefox but not in google chrome

Tags: javascript, json, file

This javascript function is working in firefox but not in google chrome how to fix it so it will work in google chrome

```
function outputCou() {      
  $.getJSON("country.json", function (data) {
    var output="";
    for (var i in data.countries) {
      output+="<li><a class='location' href=\"#intro_country\" data-phone=\"123-456-7891\" onclick=\"updateCountry(\'" + data.countries[i].File+"\');\">" + data.countries[i].Name+"</a></li>";     
    } 
    jQuery('#CountryList').html(output);
  });
}
```

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting this code to exhibit and what is currently happening when you run it in Chrome?

Comment: the details are stored in file so when a button is clicked this function has to run in firefox the function(data) is being executed but not in google chrome

Comment: Cross domain issue ([CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing))

Comment: @kohli it has to fixed only in server-side, here check this [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3136140/1671639)

Comment: is there any alternative way for it