# Strophejs XMPP Hello World cant connect to server if JS code not hosted on server (CORS?)

Tags: xmpp, cors, strophe

I am trying an example in Jack Moffit's book: Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery. Specifically, I am trying the hello world app in chapter 3, which is supposed to log into an xmpp server through a web interface using bosh. I have downloaded all the code necessary from http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/10/04705407/DOWNLOAD/9780470540718_Professional%20XMPP_Code%20Download.zip.

When I open the file Hello.html, in Chrome, and open the JavaScript Console, there are no issues, so it seems the scripts and css files referenced in the file have loaded successfully.

This is the Hello.html file:

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Hello - Chapter 3</title>

        <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css'>
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js'></script>
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js'></script>
        <script src='../scripts/strophe.js'></script>
        <script src='../scripts/flXHR.js'></script>
        <script src='../scripts/strophe.flxhr.js'></script>

        <link rel='stylesheet' href='hello.css'>
        <script src='hello.js'></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>

        <div id='log'>
        </div>

        <!-- login dialog -->
        <div id='login_dialog' class='hidden'>
          <label>JID:</label><input type='text' id='jid'>
          <label>Password:</label><input type='password' id='password'>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

And this is hello.js:

```
        var Hello = {
        connection: null,
        start_time: null,

        log: function (msg) {
            $('#log').append("<p>" + msg + "</p>");
        },

        send_ping: function (to) {
            var ping = $iq({
                to: to,
                type: "get",
                id: "ping1"}).c("ping", {xmlns: "urn:xmpp:ping"});

            Hello.log("Sending ping to " + to + ".");

            Hello.start_time = (new Date()).getTime();
            Hello.connection.send(ping);
        },

        handle_pong: function (iq) {
            var elapsed = (new Date()).getTime() - Hello.start_time;
            Hello.log("Received pong from server in " + elapsed + "ms.");

            Hello.connection.disconnect();

            return false;
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#login_dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Connect to XMPP',
            buttons: {
                "Connect": function () {
                    $(document).trigger('connect', {
                        jid: $('#jid').val(),
                        password: $('#password').val()
                    });

                    $('#password').val('');
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).bind('connect', function (ev, data) {
        var conn = new Strophe.Connection(
            "http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind");
        conn.connect(data.jid, data.password, function (status) {
            if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
                $(document).trigger('connected');
            } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
                $(document).trigger('disconnected');
            }
        });

        Hello.connection = conn;
    });

    $(document).bind('connected', function () {
        // inform the user
        Hello.log("Connection established.");

        Hello.connection.addHandler(Hello.handle_pong, null, "iq", null, "ping1");

        var domain = Strophe.getDomainFromJid(Hello.connection.jid);

        Hello.send_ping(domain);

    });

    $(document).bind('disconnected', function () {
        Hello.log("Connection terminated.");

        // remove dead connection object
        Hello.connection = null;
    });
```

Basically, what it does is connect to an XMPP server via a BOSH-service running at http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind. When it connects, it prints "Connection established" to the html file using jQuery.

However, I cant get it to connect to a server. I have checked that the bosh service at `http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind` is up and running. I have created xmpp accounts at alpha-labs.net and jabber.de. Both accounts work using pidgin IM on my Windows machine. But I cant log into either of these accounts using this example.

When I enter my jid such as justastest@alpha-labs.net and the corresponding password, nothing is printed to the screen.

I have posted to the forum of the publisher of the book as well, but it is not really frequented very often, so I figured I'd try here.

Thanks for any and all help!

C

Edit: so Ive narrowed it down a bit, and with help from some other people have determined this may be a CORS issue. So far, I had been accessing Hello.html in my web browser locally, using file:///. In this case, I can't connect to any server.

However, if I host Hello.html/hello.js on a server, and then access that version through my web browser using http, then the code works, i.e. server connection can be established.

I don't quite understand though, why this is a problem. Why does it not work if I access this locally, and can I somehow make it work in the local scenario as well?

Answer (score 0):

To enable CORS functionality, you must run your local site from a web server, not from a file.

[Here's a relevant SO answer which explains why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13154327/2686738).

Basically, because the origin of your website is a file and not a web url, when the CORS mechanism attempts to determine if the request should be allowed, it's comparing against `null`. It appears that this problem may only effect some browsers (chrome). Obviously the simple fix would be to run your html files from a local web server.