# With <script crossorigin='anonymous'>, why is a script "blocked by CORS policy"?

Tags: javascript, html

With Google Chrome or Firefox, if I try to load the following HTML:

```
<script crossorigin='anonymous' src='https://stackoverflow.com/foo.js'></script>
```

I get a CORS error like this:

> Access to Script at 'https://stackoverflow.com/foo.js' from origin 'https://stackoverflow.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource...

However, the same tag without the `crossorigin='anonymous'` attribute works fine (of course generating a 404 error, since foo.js does not exist).

This is surprising, since `anonymous` is just [supposed to prevent sending any credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes), and script tags [are not supposed to require CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530554/why-is-the-html-script-tag-not-subject-to-the-same-origin-policy). What is causing this, and what should I do?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I was confused about this for a while. Here's how I now understand it:

[According to the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#cors-settings-attribute), there are actually *three* possible values for the `crossorigin` attribute: `anonymous`, `use-credentials`, and an "missing value default" that can only be accessed by omitting the attribute. (An empty string, on the other hand, maps to `anonymous`.) The default value causes the browser to skip CORS entirely, which is the normal behavior I was expecting.

The `crossorigin` attribute should only be used if we care about getting error information for the script being loaded. Since accessing this information requires a CORS check, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header must be present on the resource for it to be loaded.

Comment: I'll leave this unaccepted for a while in case anyone wants to write up a better explanation!

Comment: pdg137 you just need to make your server returning this response header on the JS file :
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Comment: Yes, that would help, but often I can't or don't want to do that. Specifically, when loading third party scripts.

Comment: They say "missing value default", not "missing default value". See the difference? Your answer is confusing, there is no such thing here as "Unnamed default value". It is just anonymous, use-credentials or no attribute. It's not default value that skips CORS, it's missing attribute ONLY.

Comment: I edited this in an attempt to make it more clear; please let me know if that helps.

Comment: What error information is sent? I don't get it.

Comment: You should see that error in the browser console.

Answer (score 28):

`crossorigin` attribute has only two possible values: `anonymous` or `use-credentials`. Any value other than `anonymous`, including empty value, will be translated to `anonymous`.

So these three tags have the same meaning:

```
<script src="https://stackoverflow.com/foo.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackoverflow.com/foo.js" crossorigin="">
<script src="https://stackoverflow.com/foo.js" crossorigin="IamCrazy">
```

What is interesting though, is that CORS behavior is totally **disabled** if you skip `crossorigin` attribute. For example:

```
<script src="https://stackoverflow.com/foo.js">
```

This tag will run script without any CORS-related checking. In practice, no `crossorigin` attribute makes browser skip `Origin` HTTP header entirely.

No matter if your `crossorigin` is `anonymous` or `use-credentials`, request's `Origin` must still match response's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Otherwise no luck - script is never fired.

Source: [HTTP access control (CORS) on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: This is wrong. OR it is right but Chrome's implementation does not match this.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken what specifically works different in Chrome? I tested it again today and it looks like my answer is still correct. There are just three behaviors of `crossorigin`: allow all (no attribute at all), send credentials (`crossorigin="use-credentials"`) and skip credentials (any value other than `use-credentials`), officially `anonymous`, unofficially can be anything, including empty value.

Comment: It's also very clearly stated in the documentation I linked: *"An invalid keyword and an empty string will be handled as the anonymous keyword."*.

Comment: I think, that CORS can kick in AFTER resource is fetched when no crossorigin is used. As I understand, crossorigin="anonymous" forces preflight for that request while ommiting it will still enforce CORS rules but after it is fetched since no preflight is beeing made. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit old thread, but it's something that I happened to encounter, these days.
In addition to the **crossorigin**, you should also make sure that the **server** from which you are loading the script (in your example - stackoverflow.com) returns a **specific header**.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
```

Only then you will be able to receive the full information about an errors which has happened in the script.

Of course if you know for sure which **url** to allow you should use it instead of the asterisk **'*'**.

Comment: Don't put a wildcard `*` unless you know what you are doing. Much better to put: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://requestingserver.com` replacing the domain with the domain of the requesting server.

Comment: What is the difference in security value between having a * and having the value of the requesting server ? I don't see any value upgrade.

Comment: The '*' allows all the possible servers, rather than a specific value.

Comment: I know. My question is without allow-credentials: true, what is the risk here ?

Comment: And What Flimm is suggesting: "replacing it with the domain of the requesting server", that doesn't seem to offer any value upgrade in terms of security. Infact, reflecting the origin of the request (coupled with allow credentials:true) can introduce a security vulnerability in servers that uses cookies for authentication

Answer (score 3):

> This is surprising, since anonymous is just supposed to prevent sending any credentials, and script tags are not supposed to require CORS. What is causing this

The use of the word "just" there is incorrect.

See [MDN on `onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#notes):

> When an error occurs in a script, loaded from a different origin, the details of the error are not reported to prevent leaking information (see bug 363897). Instead the error reported is "Script error." This behavior can be overridden in some browsers using the `crossorigin` attribute on `<script>` and having the server send the appropriate CORS HTTP response headers.

Adding *any* `crossorigin` attribute value is supposed to allow you to do things which require CORS permission. In the case of a script that is to get useful error messages reported to `onerror` as shown in the quote above.

The cost of that is that you now require CORS permissions to do **anything** with the data. In the case of a script element, that includes executing the script (which, as you pointed out, normally doesn't require CORS permission).

The difference between `anonymous` and `use-credentials` is that the latter will *also*:

- Require a pre-flight OPTIONS request to get permission to send credentials (such as any cookies) before it will make the GET request for the script
- Send any credentials in that GET request for the script

---

> what should I do?

You can either:

- Not use the `crossorigin` attribute (which will send any credentials (such as cookies) to the server unless they get blocked by a third-party cookies policy in the browser)
- Have the server grant permission using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header
- Move the script to a different domain which doesn't have credentials associated with it (e.g. you could have `www.example.com` with cookies and `cdn.example.com` without).