# Why crossorigin="anonymous" is even needed in <script> tag?

Tags: javascript

I have seen many implementations of script tag includes attribute crossorigin="anonymous". I know the purpose of crossorigin request in context of Ajax. But why we need a crossorigin="anonymous" in  tag. Let say If I remove the crossorign attribute from `<script src="https://thirdpartyexample.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`, it will still work (I tested it in my local html file). So why it is needed at all? **In which case not using crossorigin attribute will put us in trouble?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [With <script crossorigin='anonymous'>, why is a script "blocked by CORS policy"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069330/with-script-crossorigin-anonymous-why-is-a-script-blocked-by-cors-policy)

Comment: It's much quicker to [check the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **MDN**:

> By default (that is, when the attribute is not specified), CORS is not used at all. **The "anonymous" keyword means that there will be no exchange of user credentials via cookies, client-side SSL certificates or HTTP authentication as described in the Terminology section of the CORS specification, unless it is in the same origin.**

check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin)